# "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error" If I access my site by IP address

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I deployed my site to EC2 aws web service, it worked fine if I accessed my site by domain (Ex: example.com) but I got the error below if I accessed my site by IP address (Ex: 54.175.187.xxx)

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

This is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My virtual host configuration as below,

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>        
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,E=nocache:1]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/blog/web >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All                
    </Directory>       
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Could you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is index.php in the documentroot directory? Instead all that crud a simple `FallBackResource /index.php` and `DirectoryIndex index.php` will do, but make sure the virtualhost points to the correct path, it just seems your index.php is missing. If you have access to your virtualhost configuration, please do not use .htaccess.

Comment: @ezra-s Thanks for quick response.